# tunnel Linux through windows machine

Tags: windows-7, linux, proxy, socks-proxy, reverse-tunnel

I am getting a new machine at work that I plan to have Linux (CentOS) installed. I am thinking to have a windows VM and a centos VM on top of ESXi, and CentOS will use windows VM (where I login and have access to outside world) as 'proxy'.

Why I want to do this? Here is the issue when I started in a hospital a few months ago:

- Everything runs on Windows 7
- IT knows nothing about Linux, and does not want do anything about it.
- github and like are blocked, unless you get approval for accessing "freeware" websites.

I have been approved for accessing "shareware" sites like github.com, centos.org etc. But it ties to my windows active directory log in, and IT has no clue or desire to add my linux machine to the windows active directory. The chance is very slim that I can use my active directory login for Linux.

I think it is going to work, but not sure the best way to do it. Most tutorials does not address this odd combination (windows "server" + linux client), and most only cover web browsing.

from what I read, there are a couple of possibilities:

- Windows Proxy server ( ? how to set up linux to use proxy globally)
- reverse SSH tunneling: Win --ssh--> linux, so that Linux --traffic --> win --> world
- windows shadowsocks server + linux shadowsocks client (ssclient)

But I doesn't seem to able to make either one work for all my need (browser, ftp, ssh ...)

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: There is no IT support for Linux at all. So I had to resort to 'local' solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better solution would be to install Windows 7 on your new machine, and then install Virtualbox on that.  Run CentOS as a guest in Virtualbox, and use NAT for netorking.  All of the internet requests from the CentOS VM would then NAT through your (physical) Windows machine.

Comment: Agree it is the most straightforward method. How is the performance comparing to CentOS VM +  ESXi host?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you have in mind with an ESXi host, but one concern is that ESXi has pretty limited hardware support, especially with network adapters.  Chances are very low that it will work with the onboard NIC in a desktop computer.

Comment: It will be an HP z840 workstation, which uses intel i210-t1 NIC. I think it is compatible with ESXi 6

Comment: I have installed ESXi 6.0 on an HP Z820, so I'm sure you'd be fine doing it on a Z840.  Nevertheless, I stand by my original suggestion, which I think it easier and simpler overall.  If that isn't feasible, you could try a setup with 2 NIC's on the Windows machine and use Internet Connection Sharing.